# Create unique identifier column in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[my_table]
(
    [V01_V] [real] NULL,
    [V02_V] [real] NULL,
    [V03_V] [real] NULL,
    [V04_V] [real] NULL,
    [V05_V] [real] NULL
    [Date_Inserted] [datetime] NOT NULL,
    [Unique_ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,

    CONSTRAINT [PK_row_id] 
        PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Unique_ID] ASC)
                    WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, 
                          IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, 
                          ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON, OPTIMIZE_FOR_SEQUENTIAL_KEY = OFF) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

I currently have `Unique_ID` which just captures the row number in the table. I am trying to add table information to these records, so it's easier to identify the table they are coming from.

- Table name: `april_customers`
- Current Unique_ID: 45
- Goal for Unique_ID: 04cust_45

How do I add `04cust_` to my current `Unique_ID`?

Comment: Use `ALTER TABLE`? What is the difficulty you are having adding a column to your table?

Comment: As a meta discussion, I'm a little concerned about your justification.  How could you EVER be confused about what table they came from?  You won't have a row unless you did a query, and the query tells you the table.

Comment: I don't know how to add text to the Unique_ID, which generates its values automatically.

Comment: Your request is possible, but quite unusual. If you tell us [the problem you're trying to solve with it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem), perhaps we can offer a better way to solve it.

Comment: The table name "april_customers" is a clear indication that something is left of center on the database design here. My guess is you have some view or something that pulls data from a whole pile of tables named for each month and you want to know which month a given row belongs to.

Comment: I have multiple tables for each month. I have an identifier for each table. ID 45 exists on all tables since there are +45 records for each month. My question is, how can I combine 45 with some text such as jan_45 so this becomes unique across all tables? In the future I will create new tables joining tables from different months, and I need a Unique_ID column where I can easily see what column the Unique_ID is coming from.

Comment: The real issue is that you have multiple tables for each month. That should be another column in a single table.

Comment: I know, but this is not something I can modify.

Comment: If you are truly stuck with such a horrible design you might take a look at a computed column. Something like 'MyUniqueId as 'jan_' + convert(varchar(4), Unique_ID))'. But know that is the wrong way to fix it. The best option by far is to fix the design.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would add a computed column to generate such an id

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[my_table](
    [V01_V] [real] NULL,
    [V02_V] [real] NULL,
    [V03_V] [real] NULL,
    [V04_V] [real] NULL,
    [V05_V] [real] NULL,
    [Date_Inserted] [datetime] NOT NULL,
    [Unique_ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT [PK_row_id] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED
(
    [Unique_ID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON, OPTIMIZE_FOR_SEQUENTIAL_KEY = OFF) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

```
INSERT INTO [dbo].[my_table] values (1,1,1,1,1, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP  ),(2,2,2,2,2, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP  )
```

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.my_table ADD new_id AS ('04cust_' + CONVERT(varchar(16),Unique_ID));
```

```
SELECT * FROM [dbo].[my_table]
```

| V01_V | V02_V | V03_V | V04_V | V05_V | Date_Inserted | Unique_ID | new_id |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 2023-03-20 22:37:27.493 | 1 | 04cust_1 |
| 2 | 2 | 2 | 2 | 2 | 2023-03-20 22:37:27.493 | 2 | 04cust_2 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/tRtz2q5I)

Of course you could add a uuid also, if you such problems in future

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : declaring VARCHAR without (length)](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/09/bad-habits-to-kick-declaring-varchar-without-length) - you should **always** provide a length for any `varchar` variables and parameters that you use

Comment: that is from 2009, and should be long depreacted

Comment: actually i know that Microsoft defines 30 as default, and i doubt that namy intger will get better,as long as the don't use 64 instead of 32

Comment: Good for you - but maybe your junior SQL coworker doesn't - and he sees you use `varchar` without a length - and thinks - "hey, let's do this for SQL parameters in my stored procedure, too" - and you got yourself a bug. So why don't you just use explicit length? It's easy, it makes your code **so much clearer** for yourself and anyone else who looks at it - it only has **benefits** - so just do it